# Difference between kas and kas-container

Tags: yocto

What is the difference between kas and kas-container?

The documentation says something about the other one doing something locally, but what exactly is done locally and what is the opposite of doing it locally? Googling gives examples of using either and mentions that kas-container is a script for running kas, but what exactly is the difference between them?